# what is the difference between "int b = (int) 45.0" and "int b = 45.0"?

Tags: c

I have a question.
I was wondering that by adding "(int)" (or any kind of data type), this means that we're converting it into int. ex

```
double lk = 45.0;
int nm = (int) lk; //not tested though
```

Anyway, is there a terminology for this?

Comment: Your question's body does not match the question's title.  Above, the body has been answered.  To answer the question's title: the difference is that in the first case, you're adding two `int` values, while in the second case you're adding two `double` values and then implicitly converting the result to `int`.

Comment: yes we are, for example in your subject, the first expression will assign integer to b while the second expression will attempt to assign and implicitly convert float value to integer b

Comment: @paddy sorry for that. I just didn't write more code in the title because it would confuse the readers. Anyway, the concept is the same. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: One uses an implicit conversion and the other uses explicit conversion aka cast. The net result is the same.

Comment: The initial title (now edited) and the "bland" (but correct) answer in the comment by n.m., which illustrates that the question lacks some "fire", seem to indicate that you might want to make a more complicated point. I.e. I assume that you are thinking of something else "behind" this. Consider elaborating, maybe by making an [mre] of what you are trying. Maybe the idea of an XY problem, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem , can help you making such a question. But don't get me wrong, this kind of very simple questions is absolutely fine here, if it helps you.

Comment: In some places, the compiler will automatically convert one type to another without complaint. These are generally places where type conversions are normal (like one numeric type to another) or safe (like adding a qualifier to a pointer, such as from `char *` to `const char *`). When you want to do an abnormal unsafe conversion, you must use an explicit cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[C in a Nutshell (chapter 4)](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-in-a/0596006977/ch04.html) explains the topic:

> In C, operands of different types can be combined in one operation.
>   [...] When the operands have different types, the compiler tries to
>   convert them to a uniform type before performing the operation.

This is known as **implicit type conversion**.

> You can also convert values from one type to another explicitly using
>   the cast operator [...]. You should always use the cast operator
>   whenever there is a possibility of losing information, as in a
>   conversion from `int` to `unsigned int`, for example. Explicit casts avoid
>   compiler warnings, and also signpost your program’s type conversions
>   for other programmers.

This is known as **explicit type conversion** and is done with the cast operator: `(type_name) expression`

As n.m. has already pointed pointed out, the result is the same in your example.

[Here is](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-c/) another helpful article.